# Problem referencing same libraries from multiple C# solutions

Tags: c#, reference, project

I have two C# solutions (let's say A and B). Both reference a common C# library, which is included in both solutions as a project reference. This project itself references (as a project, not DLL) another library (managed C++) which is ALSO referenced by the two top-level solutions.

Whenever one project builds successfully, the other says that the C++ library has changed and needs to be reloaded. When I do so, the C# library reference complains that it can't resolve a namespace from the C++ library. If I delete and re-add the reference to the C++ library in the C# library, the solution builds fine, but now the OTHER solution will have the same problem, and so on.

What am I doing wrong? I believe I should be able to have this sort of reference setup without problems.

Comment: is the c++ library a COM Library normal c++ referenced by dllimport or a c++ cli project

Answer (score 0):

- Right click the Solution and select Properties. Then select '...Project Build Order'. I assume we want the C++ project to build first?
- Check the Solution Properties/Common 
  Properties/Project Dependencies and
  make sure all the Depends On are set 
  right.
- Is there a possibility to move all the C++ project references to the common C# library? That way project A and B just need to reference the common project.